# Which is the better, an instance variable or a local variable for an EF context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, idisposable, using-statement

I know that the title looks a bit bad :) But I dont know how to explain my problem..

This is typically a basic problem for me but I dont know answer..

I am writing a server application which is using eneter library for client-server communinication and also it has a DAL gets data from database. as it a server application, it always need to communicate with database, so I dont know which way is more effective. (approx, max 50 clients will be connected to server)

I am using entity framework and created a model from my mysql db.

the first code is here

```
    private MyEntities ent;

    public DbHelper()
    {
     ent = new MyEntities();
    }

   void Foo()
  { 
       ent.Mytable.where......
       ....

  }
```

and second type code is

```
    void Foo()
    {
        using (MyEntities ent = new MyEntities())
        {
            ent.Mytable.where...
        }

    }
```

Can I use using statement or create a <strike>global</strike> instance variable for dal class and use it for each functions.. ?

Comment: That is not a global variable (not even `static`).

Comment: @HenkHolterman, i think u understand what I mean.. I can use this variable for in the class.. so if it is needed to change, you can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better yet, implement IDisposable on your DAL class:

```
public sealed class MyDal implements IDisposable
{
    private MyEntities ent = new MyEntities();

    void Foo()
    { 
       ent.Mytable.where......
       ....

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ent.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then...

```
using(var dal = new MyDal())
{
    dal.Foo();
    //....
}
```

Take a read [here](http://bentsai.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/idisposable-the-contentious-dispose-pattern/) about why my IDisposable is sealed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, well should I use using(var dal = new MyDal()) like that or my dal is as a local variable ?

Comment: @ertan2002 It's difficult to understand what you are asking. The variable in the `using` statement **is** a local variable.

Comment: ahh sorry i wrote wrong :S i meant instance variable of mydal class.. like MyDal dal;

Comment: You write your data access code in the DAL class, and where you need to make the data access, you wrap your `MyDal` instance in a using statement. This means that the resources held by `MyDal` get neatly disposed when you've finished your data access. Do you need your MyDal to have a lifetime longer than that?

Comment: I know what you are saying and yes if I create an instance variable of mydal class instead of using statement is better or not ? Because my application will be server and i have a doubt tht always create a local variable of mydal and after dispose it is better.. Just create on instance from mydal and use it always.. looks more logical?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 approaches are very different in terms of the scope of the change-tracking. If both work equally well then make sure to use `WithNoTracking`.

You can create a member variable for your entities like in your first code. But because you cannot write a `using(){}` statement around it the containing class should be `IDisposable`. And then the consuming class should use it inside a  `using(){}`.

Comment: thank you for editing my title and answer, well I am going to use change tracking and another things too, also I am going to use generic repository design pattern..

Answer (score 1):

From performance viewpoint it doesn't matter. Compared to the actual database interaction creating a context instance is a very fast operation.

However, you should dispose the created context in any case because it holds a database connection as a native resource.

If your want to work with a context member in your `DbHelper` class this class should implement `IDisposable` so that you can dispose the context when the `DbHelper` instance itself gets disposed:

```
public class DbHelper : IDisposable
{
    private MyEntities ent;

    public DbHelper()
    {
        ent = new MyEntities();
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Dispose() // implementation of IDisposable
    {
        ent.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You could use this class in a `using` block then:

```
using (var helper = new DbHelper())
{
     helper.Foo();
     helper.Bar();
} // helper and helper.ent gets disposed now
```

Comment: If you're not implementing full IDisposable pattern, your class **should** be `sealed`.

Comment: Thank you for answer slauma, I am asking the same question to you, need I use using(var helper ...()) instead of location variable of dbhelper class ? I cant decide which is better

Comment: @Spender `sealed` is not a requirement of the disposable pattern - a `protected virtual Dispose(bool disposing)` is the norm in a polymorphic disposable type - although maybe that is what you meant by the "full disposable pattern"  - in which case, I agree. Maybe with some GC.SuppressFinalize.

Comment: @MarcGravell, sure, it's not a requirement, but if you're not providing the tools for subclasses to dispose correctly, then sealing is a really good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what other methods exist and what they do. If you want to make changes and persist those changes using the ORM, you will need the data-context that created the objects. Also, if you want the identity manager to give you the same object instance if you query the same thing twice, you will need to use the same data-context - so you'll need to keep it handy. Finally, if the type uses lazy loading and you expect it to work - then that won't work if you have disposed the data-context.

If, however, you just want read-only access to the data without change tracking, lazy loading or identity management : dispose eagerly. And maybe consider things like micro-ORMs which simply don't have those features (deliberately, to be minimal and fast).